# Application Insight extension needed or not?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

When using the latest version of the Application Insights(AI) SDK (at time of writing: 2.4.1) in code via NuGet, is the AI extension also needed on the web app extension list in Azure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may either install the Application Insights SDK via NuGet, aka *build time*,  or enable the Application Insights site extension through the Azure Portal, aka *run time*.

If you do both, the Application Insights site extension will not work even though it is turned on.

You can refer to [the Azure Monitor documentation on Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-performance-live-website-now) for more information.

[image: Application Insights SDK and Application Insights site extension feature comparison]

Comment: Thx Fred, we also noticed that in application map you can dive more deeper in the call tree (Azure Service Bus for example) when installing the extension.

Answer (score 1):

No. The extension gives similar features as the SDK.

It is an option to use App Insights in an app without installing the SDK.